# How to copy text without copying unwanted text?

Tags: browser, copy-paste, user-interface, highlighting

I am trying to copy text in general, but there's links to parts of the page right on the left side of it. Whenever I try to copy just the text, it will highlight every text character to the left side of the screen:

[image: Screenshot of line numbers being selected]

When I paste that elsewhere, I have to remove the numbers to the left. Doing this with dozens of lines of code takes a lot of seemingly wasteful time.

How could I highlight and copy the relevant info without the numbers and links to the left of it?

PS: Before anyone might call "illegal", what I'm copying is open-source.

Comment: What web site is this? If this is Web interface to Version control software (like Trac), then often there is _view as plain text_ link somewhere next to the source code. Scroll down to the bottom of [this page](http://trac.roundcube.net/browser/subversion/trunk/roundcubemail/program/include/rcube_cache.php) to see what I mean

Comment: Sorry, that option is not available. Yes, I know what you mean though. Technically there are other ways I can think of doing this, but I'm looking to see if there's already an easier one I might not be aware of (maybe a plugin/etc. to remove links from the HTML and grab just the plain text header).

Comment: Are you open to pasting the text into a text editor and then doing a one-off regex replace to remove the unwanted text? Or are you only interested in achieving what you want at the copy step?

Comment: I'm not familiar with regular expression, but I'm open to doing it if it's more convenient and quicker than deleting it line-by-line with the mouse/keyboard. I prefer to only copy what I want and get around the trouble of removing the unwanted characters though.

Comment: @Excellll, you right. It is probably only option. Those line numbers are HTML (part of the page) and for browser it is all the same (in regards to selection) - code or link. Unless there is way to tell browser not to select any <a> elements of HTML.

Comment: @Nikolay That's why I was wondering if maybe there's a plugin or browser with support to append text-only, and not any other elements to copy.

Comment: May be this source code is available on another resource which allows plain text view...

Comment: Hey, [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bochs/?source=dlp) is the source code on sourcefourge.net

Comment: Yes, that's where I was having trouble with it. Anyways, manual marquee selection makes it easy to remove it anyways, thanks to the answer below.

Comment: What you mean 'trouble'? It is zip archive. [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bochs/files/latest/download?source=recommended) it, unpack, and open them with your favorite text editor. And you do not need browser anymore for this.

Comment: Just wanted to copy a part of one file, so no need to download and unpack all unwanted files.

Comment: I see. Well, I am happy you found workable solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holding down the ALT or CTRL will allow you to marquee select in many programs. If you move that text to Word or Reader, you should be able to use this to pick out exactly what you want to copy.

[image]

Comment: Looks promising!

Comment: Is that the picture I uploaded instead of text data?

Comment: Anyways, thanks! This did it perfectly and was what I was looking for.

Comment: I OCR'ed the text in the picture to make it selectable in Acrobat.

Comment: @PeterFitzgerald Mistake in your post there?

Comment: I pasted the recognized text in there but the line breaks got all screwy. I guess that's what I get for trying to show off :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on in which program you're trying to copy text, some editors allow the use of <kbd>ALT</kbd>+click-and-drag to select rectangular portions of text. MS Word allows this when it's in the right mood for me.